# Selecting text between two self closing tags via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I'm trying to select the text adjacent to certain self closing marker elements. Here's what I've got so far.

**Source:**

```
<markers>
    <self_closing_marker id="1"/> Some content, possible <othernodes>nodes with text</othernodes>
    <self_closing_marker id="2-3"/> Some more content
</markers>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:template name="markers" match="self_closing_marker">
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::text()" />
</xsl:template>
```

The problem being that the following sibling will select all content until the end of the current  wrapper. There are some solutions I've found using the current sibling as a variable and using preceding-sibling based off that but whenever I implement them I get empty tags.

The end goal is to get something along the lines of

```
<markers>
    <marker id="1">Some content, possible nodes with text</marker>
    <marker id="2-3">Some more content</marker>
</markers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to assign a variable `end` with the first `self_closing_marker` element on the `following-sibling::` axis.

Then, apply a predicate filter for the `text()` nodes on the `following::` axis to test whether there is an `$end` and that the first `self_closing_marker` element following that `text()` is the same as the `$end` by comparing the generated id values.

```
<xsl:template name="markers" match="self_closing_marker">
    <xsl:variable name="end" select="following-sibling::self_closing_marker[1]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="following::text()[
                            $end 
                            and generate-id(following::self_closing_marker[1]) = generate-id($end)
                          ]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Wouldn't be empty the following axis of `self_closing_marker` after the last one? Wouldn't be false the predicate for all the following text nodes?

Comment: Yes, but that may be okay if the intent is to select the text() that are between those elements (which is how I understood the requirement)

Answer (score 1):

You could look at this from the opposite direction:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="txt" match="text()" use="generate-id(preceding::self_closing_marker[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/markers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self_closing_marker"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="self_closing_marker">
    <marker id="{@id}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('txt', generate-id())"/>
    </marker>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwe3bR/1

---

If you don't want to output empty marker nodes, add a predicate to the template's match pattern:

```
<xsl:template match="self_closing_marker[key('txt', generate-id())]">
```

Comment: Using ```following-sibling::text()[1]``` will not select the text value of the other nodes between the two markers.

Resulting in missing the "possible nodes with text"

Comment: This is correct and the common _group start with_ approach in XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0):

If you're prepared to use a Saxon extension function (requires PE or higher) you could use:

```
saxon:leading(
   following-sibling::node(), 
   function($x){exists($x/self::marker)})
```

See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/leading

The function returns all items in a sequence up to the first one where the supplied predicate returns true.

You could also implement this function yourself, but because it uses higher-order functions, it still needs Saxon-PE or higher.

Otherwise, use one of the solutions other people have suggested.